# Find value with the biggest age difference

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, maxifs, excel-2021

I have a spreadsheet containing data from hospital patients. I'm running Excel 2021.
I need to create a function (or a macro) that tells me how many people live in the household that has the biggest age difference between the oldest and the youngest person. This is how my data looks like :
EDIT: I've changed the screenshot of the data for a table so it's easier to work with.

| hserial | hhsize | age |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101051 | 1 | 92 |  |  |
| 101151 | 1 | 63 |  |  |
| 101201 | 1 | 56 |  |  |
| 101271 | 2 | 38 |  |  |
| 101271 | 2 | 25 |  |  |
| 101351 | 3 | 37 |  |  |
| 101351 | 3 | 14 |  |  |
| 101351 | 3 | 10 |  |  |
| 101371 | 2 | 35 |  |  |
| 101371 | 2 | 29 |  |  |

where :
**age**: age of the patient
**hserial**: serial number of household. This is how we identify a household.
**hhsize**: household size

I was thinking on maybe using the filter function, and finding the maximum between the subtraction of the oldest and youngest of each household.

Comment: Please do not provide your data as screenshot. Insert them as text with [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) - then it is much easier to help you

Comment: Please **edit your question** to show what you have tried to solve your problem, and also add your data as **text, not a screenshot**. Suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You can use this [Markdown feature](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to put the input data. Please use a sample instead of your real data, there is no need for additional information not related to your problem. Thanks

Comment: Do you realize that there could be more than one household that could have the same age difference and different household sizes? If that is the case how the results should be presented?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have just changed it. @EEM in that case I have to display only the first value in case there are coincidences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following in `E2` cell for **O365**:

```
=LET(hs, A2:A10, hsize, B2:B10, age, C2:C10, ux, UNIQUE(hs),
 diff, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(u, LET(f, FILTER(age, hs=u), MAX(f)-MIN(f)))),
 x, XLOOKUP(MAX(diff), diff, ux), INDEX(hsize, XMATCH(x, hs)))
```

You can use instead of `INDEX/MATCH` the following `XLOOKUP(x, hs, hsize)`.

For **Excel 2021** you don't have `MAP` available, but you can use the following approach that replaces the second line of the previous formula and uses `XLOOKUP` instead of `INDEX/XMATCH`, but you can use them too:

```
=LET(hs, A2:A10, hsize, B2:B10, age, C2:C10, ux, UNIQUE(hs),
 diff, MAXIFS(age,hs, ux) - MINIFS(age,hs, ux),
 x, XLOOKUP(MAX(diff), diff, ux), XLOOKUP(x, hs, hsize))
```

Here is the output for the first formula, for the second you get the same result:
[image: excel output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, David. I wrote this code: =LET(hserial, A11:A9291, hsize, D11:D9291, age, H11:H9291, ux, UNIQUE(hserial),
 diff, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(u, LET(f, FILTER(age, hserial=u), MAX(f)-MIN(f)))),
 x, XLOOKUP(MAX(diff), diff, ux), INDEX(hsize, XMATCH(x, hserial))) And it seemes to work well. Was it correct to change the "hs" name to "hserial"? I hope that didn't affect the output. EDIT: Also I need to add that if some individual shares the same age difference, display only the first value.

Comment: @andrea65, yes you can use your formula with your specific range and use a different name. This is how it works using `INDEX/XMATCH` or `XLOOKUP`, it gets the first value. Same for the first `XLOOKUP`

Comment: I've used your formula but I neet to run this on Excel 2021, and MAP and LAMBDA functions . These are not Excel 2021 functions. What should I do?

Comment: You need to specify it in your question any excel version limitation you have via tags, so the answer will be aligned to your limitation. It will be harder for your version without a helper column. Let me think about that or maybe others with more experience in older excel version can help you.

Comment: I tried but it won't let me create tags as I don't have enough reputation. I've just modified the post but still can't figure out what changes to apply in order to make it work :(

Comment: @andrea65 I didn't know you cannot add tags. I added another solution that works for your version. removing `MAP` using a similar idea. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: I needed to create the Excel-2021 to use it. It's now available

Comment: @DavidLeal Thanks for the update, it worked perfectly. However now they are asking me that if more than one individual shares the same value, to present the first value that appears in the datablock. Should I put an @ in front of the function?

Comment: @andrea65 I am glad it worked, but solutions will return the first value, per my understanding, because `XLOOKUP` and `INDEX/XMATCH` both find the first occurrence. Don't you get that in your real example?

Comment: Yes! You're completely right. Thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2021 does not have LAMBDA functions, but you still can do so using the following:

```
=LET(rng,  A2:C11,
     hs,   INDEX(rng,,1),
     hh,   INDEX(rng,,2),
     age,  INDEX(rng,,3),
     mx,   MAXIFS(age,hs,hs),
     mn,   MINIFS(age,hs,hs),
     diff, mx-mn,
INDEX(hh,XMATCH(MAX(diff),diff)))
```

Or if it could be multiple different hhsize values with the same difference in age:

```
=LET(rng,  A2:C11,
     hs,   INDEX(rng,,1),
     hh,   INDEX(rng,,2),
     age,  INDEX(rng,,3),
     mx,   MAXIFS(age,hs,hs),
     mn,   MINIFS(age,hs,hs),
     diff, mx-mn,
UNIQUE(FILTER(hh,diff=MAX(diff))))
```

It takes the full range `A2:C11` and divides it into separate named ranges: `hs` for `hserial`, `hh` for `hhsize` and `age`.
Than it calculates the conditional max value `mx` of the `age` where the `hs` value in the range equals itself.
Same for `mn` but this is the min value.
Than diff is an array of the difference between `mx` and `mn`.

Than either INDEX / MATCH  or FILTER is used to get the `hh` value in the row of the max value in `diff`

Comment: @P.b I haven't thought about `MAXIFS`, `MINFS` using `criteria_range` and `criteria` with the same input. Great idea!

Comment: The second sentence says Excel 2021. I have to be honest I was not fully aware which functions it does/doesn't have in comparison to O 365. I found that it lacks the LAMBDA functionalities, but does have functions like LET, FILTER, UNIQUE, etc. And .. yes the other question that was closed was very unclear, also about the version.

Comment: [here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates-2021-new-functions.htm) you can find excel functions by release. It helps to find out what can be used on a given version

Comment: I was not aware of the comment in the question, I usually look at to the tag constraints. Sorry I missed that part.

Comment: Nice to know (what, no XLOOKUP?!)

Comment: on contrary `XLOOKUP` is part of the functions released on excel 2021.

Comment: @DavidLeal Sir, one can find from the Microsfot Docs as well no need to go anywhere else [Compatibility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya that is a good place too, but you find the information on specific function, not by release date having all the function added. Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah correct, but why they are not showing `FILTER()` in `Excel 2019`

Comment: Yes, if I want to be sure I check on support, but like David says, you need to know what you look for. You can't search a list of availability per version there.

Comment: reading the comments on my answer the OP didn't mention the excel version in the question initially it was added later. I found a way to circumvent `MAP` function for my approach. Using `MAXIFS`, `MINIFS` but with unique values as criteria for `ux` name I defined. Now it covers both versions. I would say @P.b could be more concise than mine if `INDEX` calls are removed using the specific ranges. It will end up with a shorter solution. Thanks!