# Get the shortest distance between two coordinates and return the adjacent cell

Tags: excel, filter, formula, pythagorean, maxifs

My spreadsheet contains data from hospital patients, based on different criteria, and one of them are household's coordinates.
The question is which household is the nearest neighbour to the household that contains the most people, based on
straight-line distances and return the hserial value for the household.
I have the households identified by their serial number:

| hserial | hhcoords | persnum |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101051 | 346350 | 1 |  |  |
| 101151 | 347312 | 1 |  |  |
| 101201 | 433616 | 1 |  |  |
| 101271 | 609464 | 1 |  |  |
| 101271 | 609464 | 2 |  |  |
| 101351 | 228562 | 1 |  |  |
| 101351 | 228562 | 2 |  |  |
| 101351 | 228562 | 3 |  |  |
| 101371 | 556408 | 1 |  |  |
| 101371 | 556408 | 2 |  |  |

**hhcoords**: (x,y) coordinates of the household location. First three digits are x, last three digits are y.
**persnum**: number of persons within the household
**hserial**: is the serial number of the household

Once you have their coords you can calculate the straightline distance between all houses, using Pythagorean Theorem.

For example, if we have the coords for a house 1 (x1,y1), and we want to know how far away it is from house 2 (x2,y2) then we can calculate a straight line distance using:

√((x1 – x2)2 + (y1 – y2)2)
The nearest neighbour is the one with the shortest distance (but careful with zeros).

I can't alter or change any of the data, even if I identify an error.

I think using the MAXIF formula would be useful as well as filtering it with FILTER, but I don't know how to aplly it to this case.

EDIT: This is my code but I have the #VALUE error:

```
=LET(hserial,UNIQUE(Table2[[#Headers],[hserial]]),hhcoords,UNIQUE(Table2[[#Headers],[hhcoords]]),hserial1,hserial,hserial2,TRANSPOSE(hserial),getXλ,LAMBDA(h,LEFT(INDEX(hhcoords,MATCH(h,hserial,0)),3)),getYλ,LAMBDA(h,MID(INDEX(hhcoords,MATCH(h,hserial,0)),4,3)),m,SQRT((getXλ(hserial1)-getXλ(hserial2))^2+(getYλ(hserial1)-getYλ(hserial2))^2),posMaxValue,MATCH(MAX(m),TOCOL(m),0),firstHH, CHOOSEROWS(hserial1,INT(posMaxValue/COUNT(hserial1)+1)),secondHH,INDEX(hserial1,MOD(posMaxValue,COUNT(hserial1))),HSTACK(firstHH,secondHH,MAX(m)))
```

Comment: Why not apply what you were shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75120588/4961700 and edit / change to suit other constraints?

Comment: As I need to calculate the distance with the Pythagorean Theorem, I don't know how to implement that into the problem.

Comment: So, it's not an Excel problem but one of mathematics...

Comment: I think, I misinterpreted your question: "I need to know which household is the nearest neighbour that contains the most people based on straight line distances" -- to which household the "nearest neighbour"?

Comment: I've edited the question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: *The question is which household is the nearest neighbour to the household that contains the most people?*  
 It seems that to be able to answer that question, one must know which house contains the most people.

Comment: @EEM Yes, the persnum column says how many people live in that household (I've updated the table)

Comment: What happens if multiple households meet the criteria:  Multiple with the same number of people, and/or multiple that are the same minimal distance from that household?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(
hserial,UNIQUE(data[hserial]),
hhcoords,UNIQUE(data[hhcoords]),

hserial1,hserial,
hserial2,TRANSPOSE(hserial),

getXλ,LAMBDA(h,LEFT(INDEX(hhcoords,MATCH(h,hserial,0)),3)),
getYλ,LAMBDA(h,MID(INDEX(hhcoords,MATCH(h,hserial,0)),4,3)),
m,SQRT((getXλ(hserial1)-getXλ(hserial2))^2+(getYλ(hserial1)-getYλ(hserial2))^2),

posMaxValue,MATCH(MAX(m),TOCOL(m),0),
firstHH, CHOOSEROWS(hserial1,INT(posMaxValue/COUNT(hserial1)+1)),
secondHH,INDEX(hserial1,MOD(posMaxValue,COUNT(hserial1))),

HSTACK(firstHH,secondHH,MAX(m)))
```

Maybe you don't have `HSTACK` - then you would have to use three formulas.

[image]

Comment: It gives me an error with the first "Tabelle1[hserial]". I have checked and I do have the HSTACK forumula

Comment: Sorry - I didn't explain that: I used a table for the data (insert > table) which is called "Tabelle1".

Comment: I updated the formula: you have to put your ranges in the first two rows. (replacing eg. data[hserial] by your range).

Comment: within a table you just reference the row, e.g. =LEFT(B3,3) - spill formulas don't work within tables, but normal formulas expand automatically

Comment: I've just created a table like you but I'm not sure on the name , I think it's Table 2. I posted the code like this and I have the #Value error now. I'll post the code on the question edited

Comment: You have to remove the [#header] parts

Comment: Do I have to write something intead? Deleting it does not solve it

Comment: I have updated the table as i was missing the number of people within the household

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `DATA` is located at `[B2:D12]`.
The serial and coordinates of the household with the most people are: `101351` and `228562`.

-. To obtain the shortest distance enter this formula in `[I7]`*(Excel 2021)*:

```
 = LET(
 lSerial, $B$3:$B$12, lCoords, $C$3:$C$12, lPers, $D$3:$D$12,
 lMaxPpl, XLOOKUP( MAX(lPers), lPers, lCoords ),
 MIN( IF( lCoords = lMaxPpl, ""N/A"",
 SQRT( ( LEFT(lMaxPpl,3) -LEFT(lCoords,3) )^2 + ( RIGHT(lMaxPpl,3) -RIGHT(lCoords,3) )^2 ) ) ) )
```

[image]

-. To obtain the serial and coordinates enter this formula in `[G7]` *(Excel 2021)*:

```
= LET( lData, $B$3:$D$12,
 lSerial, INDEX( lData, 0, 1 ), lCoords, INDEX( lData, 0, 2 ), lPers, INDEX( lData, 0, 3 ),
 lMaxPpl, XLOOKUP( MAX(lPers), lPers, lCoords ),
 lDist, IF( lCoords = lMaxPpl, ""N/A"",
 SQRT( ( LEFT(lMaxPpl,3) -LEFT(lCoords,3) )^2 + ( RIGHT(lMaxPpl,3) -RIGHT(lCoords,3) )^2 ) ),
 lRow, MATCH( MIN(lDist), lDist, 0 ),
 INDEX( lData, lRow, 1 ): INDEX( lData, lRow, 2 ) )
```

[image]

-. To obtain the serial, coordinates & distance enter this formula in `[G8]` *(Excel 365)*:

```
= LET( lData, $B$3:$D$12,
 lSerial, INDEX( lData, 0, 1 ), lCoords, INDEX( lData, 0, 2 ), lPers, INDEX( lData, 0, 3 ),
 lMaxPpl, XLOOKUP( MAX(lPers), lPers, lCoords ),
 lDist, IF( lCoords = lMaxPpl, ""N/A"",
 SQRT( ( LEFT(lMaxPpl,3) -LEFT(lCoords,3) )^2 + ( RIGHT(lMaxPpl,3) -RIGHT(lCoords,3) )^2 ) ),
 CHOOSEROWS( HSTACK( DROP( lData, , -1 ), lDist ),
 MATCH( MIN(lDist), lDist, 0 ) ) )
```

[image]

**Evaluation of the [LET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999):**

`lData, $B$3:$D$12`: Sets the range to work with as `lData`, having the entire data range as one `name` makes easier the maintenance of the formula, i.e. if the range size changes only this name needs to be adjusted. However, I would suggest the use of `Excel Tables` as formulas are automatically updated when the size of the table changes.

`lSerial, INDEX( lData, 0, 1 )`, `lCoords, INDEX( lData, 0, 2 )` and `lPers, INDEX( lData, 0, 3 )` the columns to be used in the calculations.

`lMaxPpl, XLOOKUP( MAX(lPers), lPers, lCoords )`: Gives the coordinates of the household with most people.

`lDist, IF( lCoords = lMaxPpl, ""N/A"", SQRT( ( LEFT(lMaxPpl,3) -LEFT(lCoords,3) )^2 + ( RIGHT(lMaxPpl,3) -RIGHT(lCoords,3) )^2 ) )`: Calculates the distances of all other households from the one with most people.

`lRow, MATCH( MIN(lDist), lDist, 0 )`: Gives the row of the shortest distance.

`INDEX( lData, lRow, 1 ): INDEX( lData, lRow, 2 )`: Use to return the first two columns from the data *(not sure if `HSTACK` or any other alternative is available in Excel 2021)*.

`DROP( lData, , -1 )`: Excludes the last column from the data range.

`HSTACK( DROP( lData, , -1 ), lDist )`: Combines the *adjusted* data range and the *calculated distances* as one array.

`CHOOSEROWS( HSTACK( DROP( lData, , -1 ), lDist ), MATCH( MIN(lDist), lDist, 0 ) )`: Returns the entire row with the shortest distance from the combined array.

For documentation on the functions used see the following pages:
[CHOOSECOLS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choosecols-function-bf117976-2722-4466-9b9a-1c01ed9aebff),
[DROP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34),
[HSTACK function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2),
[SQRT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sqrt-function-654975c2-05c4-4831-9a24-2c65e4040fdf),
[XLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929).

Comment: I can't obtain the "shortest distance from"

Comment: Did you updated the formula with your ranges? What’s the location of your data? Is any of the functions not available in your excel version?